# Firebase Admin SDK pagination not working with query

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a large dataset that I need to query. I've built a firebase function that should query my collection in batches of 5000 documents per pagination. If I remove the `.orderBy("willowROI").where("willowROI", ">",0)` from the initial snapshot and the snapshot in the while loop, the function performs as expected, but when I introduce the query, the first 5000 rows are returned, but no additional rows are returned (There are about 150,000 documents in total in the collection, and with the query there should be roughly 70,000 documents). I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**UPDATE** I have verified the index for this query is added to firestore and tested this query in the front-end to ensure the query works.

```
exports.getBatchedPrograms = async (req, res) => {
  const limit = 5000;

  const array = [];
  const first = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("programs")
    .orderBy("willowROI")
    .where("willowROI", ">", 0)
    .orderBy("providerCIPCred")
    .limit(limit);

  const snapshot = await first.get();

  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    array.push({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    });
  });

  // Get the last document
  let last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];

  let currentLength = snapshot.docs.length;

  while (currentLength > 0) {
    const next = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("programs")
      .orderBy("willowROI")
      .where("willowROI", ">", 0)
      .orderBy("providerCIPCred")
      .startAfter(last.data().providerCIPCred)
      .limit(limit);

    const snapshot = await next.get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      array.push({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      });
    });

    currentLength = snapshot.docs.length;
    last = snapshot.docs[currentLength - 1];
  }
  res.send(array);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From the behavior you're describing you miss a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes) that the query needs. The easiest way to create the necessary index is usually to add a `try-catch` and log the error you get, as that includes a URL with all the necessary data for the index pre-populated. If that doesn't work, you can always create it manually as shown in the documentation on [managing indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

Comment: It doesn't throw any index errors, I manually added an index just in case, but no change in behavior. Also, if I run the exact same query from a component instead of from a could function, the query runs fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, that last bit makes it clear that it's not an index issue. I'd recommend clarifying that in the question, as I'll likely delete my answer to make it clearer to others that this problem hasn't been addressed.